# a function cannot approach two different limits near $a$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis

> A function cannot approach two different limits near $a$. In other words, if $f$
> approaches $l$ near $a$, and $f$ approaches $ m $ near $a$,then $m=l$.

the concept and the proof of this theorem are clears,but when i tried to imagine it, i  have some problem, because if we imagine a function approach to $l$ near $a$ we can see that for any$l$ there are some numbers whose very close to $l$,so in the same time $f$ approach to those numbers .for explaine my idea ,let's take $f(x)=x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})$,suppose that $f$ approach to $0$and let's take $ \epsilon =\frac{1}{10}$,

that's mean $|x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})|< \frac{1}{10}$ $(*)$

we know that : $|x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})|<|x^2|$

so for ensure  $(*)$ is true we can put $|x^2|< \frac{1}{10}$

$\Rightarrow$ $|x|< \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$

so for getting $f$ approach to $0$ we must to require that  $|x-0|< \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$
wich is equal $3,16$,finally that's mean if the distance between $x$ and $0$ is smaller than $3.16$ then $f$ approach to $0$.

### now let's take the same function $f(x)=x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})$,suppose that $f$ approach to $\frac{1}{10}$

let's take $ \epsilon =\frac{1}{10}$,

that's means $|x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{10}|< \frac{1}{10}$ $(**)$

after some algebraic manipulation we will get ; for  ensure  $(**)$ is true we can put $|x^2|< \frac{2}{10}$

$\Rightarrow$ $|x|< \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{10}}$ wich is also equal $3,16$

so for getting $f$ approach to $\frac{1}{10}$ we must to require that  $|x-0|< \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{10}}$,that's mean if the distance between $x$ and $0$ is smaller than $3.16$ then $f$ approach to $\frac{1}{10}$.

so finally  if we take   the distance between $x$ and $0$ is smaller than $3.16$ then we will have $f$ approach to $\frac{1}{10}$ and $f$ approach to $0$ and this is a contradiction .

so were is the problem here?

Comment: please,  i need an editor for edit my question

Comment: @ Stinking Bishop
 $-\frac{2}{10}<0<x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})|< \frac{2}{10}$ so $|x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x})|<\frac{2}{10}$,so it is enought to take$ |x^2|<\frac{2}{10}$!!

Comment: $\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{10}\right|<\frac{1}{10}$ *implies* $\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|<\frac{2}{10}$ but is not equivalent to it. The latter does not imply the former.

Comment: Unless you're asking something different than what I think you're asking (I think you're asking about [uniqueness of limit](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uniqueness+of+limit%22+%22real+analysis%22)), you should say "at $a$" instead of "near $a$". Although the behavior of a function near $a$ is relevant, the point $a$ remains fixed. Indeed, a reasonable interpretation of "a function cannot approach two different limits near $a$" is not true for something like $\sin(1/x)$ or $x\sin(1/x)$ or $x^2\sin(1/x)$ or $\ldots$ (here I'm interpreting "near $a$" to mean in every neighborhood of $a).$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ independently in the definition of a limit. Whether or not $|f(x)-L|$ is arbitrarily small depends on the choice of $\delta$ in the first part of the definition. The algorithm is:

1. Fix $\epsilon>0$.
2. Find a $\delta$ (usually a function of $\epsilon$) such that $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

What you've done is that you've found an interval in which $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is less than $1/10$, not that it has a limit of $1/10.$